# (Napalm Automation) Getting indent error after using try except block while testing opening file/cisco switch with "with"

Tags: python-3.5

Getting an IndentationError: expected an indented block

I am trying to connect to a device with the wrong credentials on purpose to test authentication exception. If I remove the try block and ensure block of code is written `enter code here`with correct syntax it runs fine. Meaning the program will crash like its suppose to. However if i do use the correct username and password it works fine. Only when i do the try block do i get the above error.

```
from napalm import get_network_driver
from getpass import getpass
from netmiko import NetMikoAuthenticationException


username = input('username')
password = getpass('password')
driver = get_network_driver('ios')
with open('devices.txt','r') as switch_db:
    for switch in switch_db:
    #set up to connect to a switch from switch_db
        try:
            with driver(switch, username, password) as device:

        except NetMikoAuthenticationException:
            print('Authentication Error!')
```

Comment: When i do use the wrong password and the program does not have the try block, i do get the expected exception which i am trying to catch. "netmiko.ssh_exception.NetMikoAuthenticationException: Authentication failure: un able to connect cisco_ios 192.168.122.250:22
Authentication failed."

Comment: Your block `with driver(switch, username, password) as device:` is empty. whenever you start a block you need atleast one line of code to be executed. Yours is empty which is resulting the error.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the with context manager line i was using is considered an empty try block so i changed the code to take an action to set a variable to the connection call. of course this works but you will have to remember to close the connection in your code.

```
from pprint import pprint
from napalm import get_network_driver
from getpass import getpass
from netmiko import NetMikoAuthenticationException
import json


username = input('username')
password = getpass('password')
driver = get_network_driver('ios')

with open('devices.txt','r') as switch_db:
    for switch in switch_db:
    #set up to connect to a switch from switch_db
        try:
            device = driver(switch, username, password)
            device.open()
        except NetMikoAuthenticationException:
            print('Authentication Error!')
            username = input('username')
            password = getpass('password')
            device = driver(switch, username, password)
            device.open()
        else:
            print('line after try block')
            pprint(device.get_interfaces())
            device.close()
            print('switch is closed')'
```

Answer (score 0):

Replying here as well so SO can see this too.

You have an empty with constructor inside of the try/except block. This works and was tested against Cisco DevNet Sandbox.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from napalm import get_network_driver
from getpass import getpass
from netmiko import NetMikoAuthenticationException
from napalm.base.exceptions import ConnectionException
from pprint import pprint


username = input('username: ')
password = getpass('password: ')
driver = get_network_driver('ios')
with open('devices.txt','r') as switch_db:
    for switch in switch_db:
    #set up to connect to a switch from switch_db
        try:
            with driver(switch, username, password, optional_args={'port': 8181}) as device:
                pprint(device.get_facts())
        except NetMikoAuthenticationException:
            print('Authentication Error!')
        except ConnectionException:
            print(f'Could not connect to {switch}')
```